# PHP - Contact form not working (message not sent)

Tags: php, contacts

I'm currently using Godaddy webmail service. Basically, the problem with this contact form is that you can submit the message, but it doesn't get sent. (**Note:** The email address in the '$email_to' area is not the actual email that I used to test the form.).

Below is the code.

```
<?php

// Set email variables
$email_to = 'randomaddress@gmail.com';
$email_subject = 'Form submission';

// Set required fields
$required_fields = array('fullname','email','comment');

// set error messages
$error_messages = array(
    'fullname' => 'Please enter a Name to proceed.',
    'email' => 'Please enter a valid Email Address to continue.',
    'comment' => 'Please enter your Message to continue.'
);

// Set form status
$form_complete = FALSE;

// configure validation array
$validation = array();

// check form submittal
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    // Sanitise POST array
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) $_POST[$key] = remove_email_injection(trim($value));

    // Loop into required fields and make sure they match our needs
    foreach($required_fields as $field) {       
        // the field has been submitted?
        if(!array_key_exists($field, $_POST)) array_push($validation, $field);

        // check there is information in the field?
        if($_POST[$field] == '') array_push($validation, $field);

        // validate the email address supplied
        if($field == 'email') if(!validate_email_address($_POST[$field])) array_push($validation, $field);
    }

    // basic validation result
    if(count($validation) == 0) {
        // Prepare our content string
        $email_content = 'New Website Comment: ' . "\n\n";

        // simple email content
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if($key != 'submit') $email_content .= $key . ': ' . $value . "\n";
        }

        // if validation passed ok then send the email
        mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_content);

        // Update form switch
        $form_complete = TRUE;
    }
}

function validate_email_address($email = FALSE) {
    return (preg_match('/^[^@\s]+@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}$/i', $email))? TRUE : FALSE;
}

function remove_email_injection($field = FALSE) {
   return (str_ireplace(array("\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d", "Content-Type:", "bcc:","to:","cc:"), '', $field));
}

?>
```

Comment: Try to print all variables to find where the script ends.

Comment: change the email_to address/get last error on mail shooting by error_get_last...this will enable you track the exact error..

Comment: can you run a simple mail function to check the mail is working or not - 
`<?php echo mail('someone@example.com', 'Mail sub', 'Mail Body') ; ?>`
and paste the output here?

Answer (score 0):

check your server. SMTP is enable or not, if SMTP not enable please set up SMTP.